# Prompt a confirmation page for a form with FileInput field in Django

Tags: django, file-io

I'm developing an admin interface (without a model) for a data restore process. The form on the page allows user to upload a restore file. Now, what I'd like to do is, when the user submit the form, I want to upload the file first, pre-process it, then show a confirmation page to user.

In the pre-process, assuming the form is valid, I unpackage the restore file and extract the backup time from it, then show the backup time (and possibly other information from the restore file) to user in the confirmation page.

My problem is I don't know what the best way is to save the file state. Ideally I'd like to pass the uploaded file to the confirmation page form then when user agrees to continue, I use the restore file to actually restore the system. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

So what I did was to save the file first, then somehow include the filepath in the confirmation page in a hidden field. However, there's a security risk by doing this since the filepath can be modified when user submits the confirmation form.

What's the best way to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the filepath location in the [session](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views). You can access the session from your view:

```
def your_view(request):
    ...
    request.session['file_path'] = 'the file path'
```

Then in another view get it out:

```
def your_other_view(request):
    ...
    request.session.get('file_path')
```

and pass it to your template for use.

You don't have to worry about security, (from the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions)):

> It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. Cookies contain a session ID – not the data itself.

Comment: This answer is way better than mine - looks like I'm going to have to go back and update some code.

Comment: Be aware that the cookie contains also the data if the session is cookie based (the default is database based).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to solve this problem using a model, that keeps track of a file, and when it was last updated/uploaded. That way in your hidden input you can embed an ID you retrieve later - so if an attacker wants to mess with your form field, all they're going to get is a different backup file (and you could probably write extra validation to handle that).

I'd recommend you create a temporary model to handle your file for you, and then just delete it when you're done processing the file (at the end of the second step).